# How to call a php method using OnClick

Tags: php

I'm new with `php` and I'm facing very difficult on understanding how it works. I work with C# windowsForm and Asp.Net so that's why i'm having so much difficult.

I have a `form`:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Numero 1</title></head>
    <body>
        <form  method='post' action="01.php">

        Valor da Conta de Luz <input type="text"  name="Valor" />
        <input type="submit" value="Verificar Valor" onclick="ValorConta()" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the same file i have my `php`

```
<?php   
    function ValorConta()
    {
        $TxtValor = $_POST["TxtValor"]; 

        if($TxtValor > 50)
        {
            echo "Você está gastando muito !";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "seu gasto é normal !";
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to call this method `ValorConta` by the click of my button, and pass as `parameter` the value of the `textbox`... It's so easy with C# but now I have no idea how to do this... And my teacher is not going so well explaining it to me. Any help ?

Comment: You can not call a php script with the onclick element, you can only call javascript. You could use javascript to call php which is called an AJAX call. Googling for AJAX will give you extensive reading material

Comment: Ok... GOt it! What if we forgot the "onclick" function... How would I do to pass parameters to my php function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: with an AJAX call to the PHP script, specifying parameters that allow you to execute that certain method. That's because the PHP script is interpreted before you get the actual page and all the PHP code is executed. Then, JS methods cannot execute any PHP code because, as you can see if you check the source code of the page you get in the browser, there is none left in your page!

Hence, given the fact you're mixing the function containing some logic, with some presentation output, you have to separate them in two php scripts. Then, the AJAX call with get only the ouput you need.

You must write your new PHP script aiming at receiving parameters that definbe which method to execute and with what data as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP file containing the function `ValorConta()` is called `01.php` and located in the same directory as your HTML file, this should just work.

Be aware however, that PHP is executed on the server, not on the client. So you can't use `onclick` to call a PHP function. The only thing that can trigger a PHP function is a new HTTP request to a PHP script calling that function. This can for example be achieved by sending a form via POST as you do in your HTML file.